# Table view cells are not deallocated after tableview referencing them is deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory-leaks

How do the table view cells (or collection view cells) are deallocated? I have a simple `UIViewController` with `UITableView` in it. The `UITableViewCell` is added as prototype cell through `UIStoryboard`. The `UIViewController` is deallocated properly but not the cells. The instances of tableview cells are still present in the memory graph of Xcode. It must be deallocated as the `UITableView` referencing it is deallocated.

Comment: Add your code so we can take a look at it. Is your `UITableView` a weak reference?

Comment: @BoldLion the code just contains simple `UITableView` data sources methods with just dequeing the cells. No extra functionality has been added to it. and  yes `UITableView` is a weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Cells are cached by the table when they are moved off the screen. There's no global cache.**

As long as you return an autoreleased cell in "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" the cell will be destroyed, when the tableView is destroyed.

Table views don't tend to allocate and deallocate table view cells much. Creating cells is expensive, so they get reused when possible, rather than being discarded when they go off screen.

The UITableViewDelegate method `-tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is the better place to update cells to cancel downloads or other no-longer-relevant operations.

You go now and have an awesome day!